# Arquillian test: could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: jsf, selenium, jsf-2, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to add Arquillian + Selenium test to my jsf application. The problem is that when I try to run the tests (on tomcat 7, with command `mvn test`), the browser opens and displays the error: `HTTP Status 500 - Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory`.

I did some search and found, that adding `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` to my web.xml can help. It helps - the test runs without errors, but I get plenty of warnings of the form:

`WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named '<myBeanName>' has already been registered. Replacing existing managed bean class type <Path to bean class> with <Path to bean class>`

where both paths are the same. Without the ConfigureListener, application runs without errors and warnings (but the tests fail).

I'm using:

- Arquillian 1.1.2 Final
- Arquillian Container Tomcat Embedded 7 1.0.0.CR5
- Graphene webdriver 2.0.0.Final
- Mojarra 2.1.22

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory" in arquillian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680947/illegalstateexception-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-context-fa)